# Is there a way to modify Google C/C++ formatter in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I like Google formatting option for C/C++ extension in VCS. However, there is one aspect I would like to change.

I prefer associating a pointer or a reference to the type declaration:

```
int& a = b;
int* c = d;
```

However, Google formatter changes it to:

```
int &a = b;
int *c = d;
```

I am wondering if there is a way to override just this formatting aspect. Regards.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html might help

Comment: I was also of the same opinion. Because it is an 'int pointer' right? But what do you do when you have two int pointers? 
`int* a, *b;`

That is why it is preferred to keep the * near the variable instead of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [clang-format-reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> #### DerivePointerAlignment `(bool)`
>
> If `true`, analyze the formatted file for the most common alignment
> of `&` and `*`. **Pointer and reference alignment styles are going
> to be updated according to the preferences found in the file.**
> `PointerAlignment` is then used only as fallback.

Consider an example code:

```
int b = 10;
int *d = &b;
int & a = b;
int *c = d;
```

If you try to format this code in VS Code, you will find that the 3rd line has automatically formatted as `int &a = b`. Again, consider the same version of code in different style:

```
int b = 10;
int* d = &b;
int & a = b;
int* c = d;
```

Now, you will see the 3rd line as: `int& a = b`.

Comment: Thank you Rohan. Guess I need to copy "Google" formatter from somewhere and modify this token. Where can I get it?